# Помогите с запросом

Tags: php, mysql

Есть вот такой скрипт вывода и подсчета количества данных, что я делаю не так?

```
<table border="1">
<?php 
$res = mysql_query("SELECT t1.`count`, COUNT(t1.`count`) FROM (SELECT `name`, COUNT(*) as `count`FROM `clinet` GROUP BY `name`) AS t1 GROUP BY t1.`count`");
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res)) {
echo '<tr>';
echo '<td>'.$row['t1'].'</td>';
echo' <td>'.$row['count'].'</td>';
}
?> 
</table>
```

Comment: Покажите структуру базы данных.

Comment: А что выдаётся? какие сообщения об ошибках?

Comment: так что за ошибка? может tr забыли закрыть?

Comment: по-моему подзапрос идентичен первому селекту..

Comment: Ты вот что сделал. 1 посчитал количество всех идентичных имён. 2 Посчитал все количества количество идентичных имён. Например у тебя 15 имён "Сергей" 10 - "Аня" и 15 "Вадим". Так подзапрос вернет 15, 10, 15. А потом ты считаешь количество идентичных имён. То есть у тебя в результате будет 2 и 1 поскольку 2-15 и 1-10. Ты скажи какой результат тебе нужен.